# How do I properly find double entries in two files in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, unique

Let's say I have two files with lists of ip-addresses. Lines in the first file are unique. Lines in the second may or may not be the same as in the first one.

What I need is to compare two files, and remove possible doubles from the second file in order to merge it with the base file later.

I've managed to write the following code and it seems to work properly, but I have a solid feeling that this code can be improved or I may be totally missing some important concept.

Are there any ways to solve the task without using complex data structures, i.e. hashrefs?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $base = shift @ARGV;
my $input = shift @ARGV;
my $res = 'result.txt';

open ("BASE","<","$base");
open ("INP","<","$input");
open ("RES", ">", "$res");

my $rhash = {}; # result hash

while (my $line = <BASE>) {chomp($line); $rhash->{$line}{'res'} = 1;} # create uniq table
while (my $line = <INP>) { chomp($line); $rhash->{$line}{'res'}++; $rhash->{$line}{'new'} = 1; } # create compare table marking it's entries as new and incrementing double keys 
close BASE;
close INP;

for my $line (sort keys %$rhash) {
    next if $line =~ /\#/; # removing comments
    printf("%-30s%3s%1s", $line, $rhash->{$line}{'res'}, "\n") if $rhash->{$line}{'res'} > 1; # kinda diagnosti output of doubles
    if (($rhash->{$line}{'new'}) and ($rhash->{$line}{'res'} < 2)) {
        print RES "$line\n"; # printing new uniq entries to result file
    }
}
close RES;
```

Comment: The `printf` line says that the line has either been seen in file1 and (file2 1 or more times)  OR more than once in file2. The `print` line if the line is unique in file2 only. I think a hash is necessary to solve your problem. And I'm not sure your code accomplishes  your goal.

Comment: Come to think of it, perhaps your code is the solution you want - lines in file2 that occur only once that are not in file1!

Comment: Let's assume that lines in file2 are uniq __for the file2__, it can be achived for example by runnign `uniq` unix command as an extreme measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly file1 and file2 each contain ips (unique in each file) And you want to get ips in file2 not in file1. If so, then maybe the following code achieves your goal.

Although it seems your code will do it, this might be clearer.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $base = shift @ARGV;
my $input = shift @ARGV;
my $res = 'result.txt';

open ("BASE","<","$base") or die $!;
open ("INP","<","$input") or die $!;
open ("RES", ">", "$res") or die $!;

my %seen;

while (my $line = <BASE>) {
    chomp $line;
    $seen{$line}++;
}
close BASE or die $!;

while (my $line = <INP>) {
    chomp $line;
    print RES "$line\n" unless $seen{$line}; # only in file2 not in file1
}
close INP or die $!;
close RES or die $!;
```